# Migrate .gitlab-ci.yml from Terraform to OpenTofu

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, opentofu

I'am using GitLab CI to run a Terraform pipeline. But, as The Terraform CI/CD templates are deprecated since this month (**Feb 2024**) and will be removed. I want to switch to OpenTofu:

[image: Terraform CI/CD templates deprecated since Feb 2024]

Problem: I followed the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/explore/catalog/components/opentofu) to make the conversion but end-up with errors.

In the most basic conversion try (see **B]**), I end up with this error:

> plan job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, fmt,
> validate, plan, apply, .post

When I define the `fmt` stage as defined [here](https://gitlab.com/explore/catalog/components/opentofu#usage) (see **C]**) , I get:

> fmt: unknown keys in `extends` (.opentofu:fmt)

**Does anyone have an idea on what to do ?**

**A]** original `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
include:
  - template: Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml   # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  # If not using GitLab's HTTP backend, remove this line and specify TF_HTTP_* variables
  TF_STATE_NAME: iam
  TF_CACHE_KEY: iam
  TF_ROOT: provisioning

stages:
  - validate
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
  - cleanup

fmt:
  extends: .terraform:fmt
  needs: []

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: []

build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: prepare

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
```

**B]** `.gitlab-ci.yml` conversion try 1:

```
include:
  - component: gitlab.com/components/opentofu/validate-plan-apply@0.17.0
    inputs:
      version: 0.17.0
      opentofu_version: 1.6.1
      root_dir: provisioning
      state_name: iam

stages: [fmt, validate, plan, apply]
```

**C]** `.gitlab-ci.yml` conversion try 2:

```
include:
  - component: gitlab.com/components/opentofu/validate-plan-apply@0.17.0
    inputs:
      version: 0.17.0
      opentofu_version: 1.6.1
      root_dir: provisioning/
      state_name: iam
  - template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml   # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

stages: [fmt, validate, plan, apply]

fmt:
  extends: [.opentofu:fmt]

...:
  extends: ...
```

**NB:** The lock file is correctly converted and `tofu plan` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after a few more tries, I realized the stages were not good. It works with:

```
include:
  - component: gitlab.com/components/opentofu/validate-plan-apply@0.17.0
    inputs:
      version: 0.17.0
      opentofu_version: 1.6.1
      root_dir: provisioning/
      state_name: iam

variables:
  TF_STATE_NAME: iam

stages: [validate, build, deploy]
```

**But I still don't find a solution for SAST.**

=> `- template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml` does not works.